# Calculate Cartesian Product of Finite Sets with Sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

It seems that the last line of following sympy code should return "True"

```py
a = ProductSet(FiniteSet(1),FiniteSet(2))
b = FiniteSet((1,2))
simplify(Eq(a ,b))
```

but instead it returns this horrible error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/sympy/sympy/simplify/simplify.py", line 557, in simplify
    return _eval_simplify(**kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/sympy/sympy/core/relational.py", line 627, in _eval_simplify
    e = super(Equality, self)._eval_simplify(**kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/sympy/sympy/core/relational.py", line 290, in _eval_simplify
    r = r.func(*[i.simplify(**kwargs) for i in r.args])
AttributeError: 'ProductSet' object has no attribute 'simplify'
```

Is there any way to get sympy to actually compute the cartesian product of finite sets?

Comment: Looking a `ProductSet` docs, I can do `set(a)==set(b)` and get `True`.  I don't know why but `Eq` must not be right tool to use with these sets.  `a` and `b` have a `intersect` method.

Comment: Aha! `Eq(b.intersect(a),b)` does the trick! How strange indeed that just using `Eq` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @hpaulj if you put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of sympy you are using but current master gives:

```
In [1]: a = ProductSet(FiniteSet(1),FiniteSet(2)) 
   ...: b = FiniteSet((1,2)) 
   ...: simplify(Eq(a ,b))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3a3ef38457b0> in <module>
      1 a = ProductSet(FiniteSet(1),FiniteSet(2))
      2 b = FiniteSet((1,2))
----> 3 simplify(Eq(a ,b))

~/current/sympy/sympy/sympy/simplify/simplify.py in simplify(expr, ratio, measure, rational, inverse, doit, **kwargs)
    559     _eval_simplify = getattr(expr, '_eval_simplify', None)
    560     if _eval_simplify is not None:
--> 561         return _eval_simplify(**kwargs)
    562 
    563     original_expr = expr = collect_abs(signsimp(expr))

~/current/sympy/sympy/sympy/core/relational.py in _eval_simplify(self, **kwargs)
    555         from sympy.solvers.solveset import linear_coeffs
    556         # standard simplify
--> 557         e = super()._eval_simplify(**kwargs)
    558         if not isinstance(e, Equality):
    559             return e

~/current/sympy/sympy/sympy/core/relational.py in _eval_simplify(self, **kwargs)
    308             if dif.is_comparable:
    309                 v = dif.n(2)
--> 310             elif dif.equals(0):  # XXX this is expensive
    311                 v = S.Zero
    312             if v is not None:

AttributeError: 'Complement' object has no attribute 'equals'
```

That's a bug in `Relational._eval_simplify` since it apparently assumes that both `lhs` and `rhs` are `Expr` which should be true for `LessThan` etc but not for `Equality`.

It shouldn't be too hard to implement `Eq` for sets since `Eq(A, B)` should be equivalent to `A.is_subset(B) and B.is_subset(A)`. Only one of those gives a definite answer at the moment though:

```
In [6]: a
Out[6]: {1} × {2}

In [7]: b
Out[7]: {(1, 2)}

In [8]: print(a.is_subset(b))
None

In [9]: print(b.is_subset(a))
True
```

A handler could be added to evaluate `a.is_subset(b)` where `a` is a `ProductSet` and `b` is a `FiniteSet`.